# While running truffle migrate it gives me this error

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, truffle, decentralized-applications

**truffle migrate it gives me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocWA1.png)**

I can't migrate the contracts. Here´s what I do:

```
truffle init
truffle compile
truffle migrate
```

Comment: its work for me , my versions : Truffle v5.4.26 (core: 5.4.26) Node v16.13.2

Comment: Truffle v5.4.29 (core: 5.4.29)
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v16.13.0
Web3.js v1.5.3

Comment: please make a new folder and run following again , and then send its errors in this post (not image) : 
truffle init
truffle compile
truffle migrage

Comment: C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test>truffle init

Starting init...
================

> Copying project files to C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test

Init successful, sweet!

Try our scaffold commands to get started:
  $ truffle create contract YourContractName # scaffold a contract
  $ truffle create test YourTestName         # scaffold a test

http://trufflesuite.com/docs

Comment: C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test>truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Emscripten.clang


C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test>
C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test>
C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test>
C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test>

Comment: C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test>truffle migrage

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
> Artifacts written to C:\Users\ibrah\OneDrive\Bureau\test\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.11+commit.d7f03943.Emscripten.clang

Comment: > Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network at http://127.0.0.1:7545. Check your network configuration.

Could not connect to your Ethereum client with the following parameters:
    - host       > 127.0.0.1
    - port       > 7545
    - network_id > 5777
Please check that your Ethereum client:
    - is running
    - is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" or "--http" option is used in geth)
    - is accessible over the network
    - is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)

Truffle v5.4.29 (core: 5.4.29)
Node v16.13.0

Comment: all your 3 steps are true. just you should run a local test network like 'ganache'. please install ganache and run it and then try truffle migrage (or truffle migrate) command again. https://trufflesuite.com/ganache/

Comment: i alredy have ganache installed